# User's can't open android application on their phone, they have to open from the android market

Tags: android, google-play

I have an application on the Android market however after a recent update a lot of users are complaining that they can't open the application on their phone by clicking on the icon, instead they have to find the application on the market and click the open button. Does anyone know why this might be?

edit: For a bit more info I recently started creating the apk file. Before it was done in a batch script that looked like

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\jarsigner" -verbose -keystore C:\Users\...\keystore\android.keystore "C:\Users\...\release\OurApp (android).apk" androidkey
C:\Users\...\dev\android-sdk-windows\tools\zipalign -f -v 4 "C:\Users\...\release\OurApp (android).apk" "C:\Users\...\release\OurApp.apk"
@pause
```

When I started doing it, I just used the Eclipse Android Tools to export a signed application package with the name OurApp.apk. I realize from looking at his script that I didn't zipalign it either. Could either of these be the reason for it not working for some users?

edit 2: After looking at the docs I found out that the android export does the zipalign automatically

> When using Eclipse with the ADT plugin, the Export Wizard will automatically zipalign your .apk after it signs it with your private key.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What exactly happens when the icon is pressed? An error, or just nothing? And are the icons on the home screen or in the applications menu?

Comment: Again I have never reproduced the problem, I only have what users are saying on the market like:

"It was great until I updated it and now I can't open from the icon on my phone."

"Doesn't let me open from my phone? :/"

"Won't let me open from my phone. Thought it was great till i updated."

"Since the last 2 updates, it won't open on my phone, only the market. Fix this or I'll Uninstall"

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like this happens sometimes when the main launcher activity is changed. In my case I added a splash screen activity that became the new launcher activity. It only seems to happen to HTC users. The solution for these users is to uninstall and then install the application again. Seems really broken to me, resulted in a lot of negative reviews.

Comment: Not only HTC devices. I got this issue on many devices as well. Once you changed the Launch Activity, it happen. And yes the right solution is to delete the app and reinstall it as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have these lines under your main activity in you manifest?

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Yes I do. All the devices I've tried it on (downloading the app from the market and opening it from the icon on the phone) work fine, but there are at least half a dozen people with reviews on the android market saying it won't open for them.

Comment: strange indeed. I'm afraid i can't help then

Comment: Is there a possibility of a package naming conflict with software preinstalled on the problematic devices?

Comment: Possibly but I'm pretty sure it would force the user to uninstall the older package in that case.

Comment: This could be possible, can you elaborate a bit more on what you mean? I just started creating the apk file, someone else was doing it before. I am using the android tool in Eclipse to export the signed application package, whereas the person before was using a batch script they wrote. We are both using the same keystore though. Could this have anything to do with it?

Comment: Going to post his batch script in my original post

Comment: Have you logged onto the main android publishing set to see if there is any correlation between the percentage of people having problems and the percentage of a certain device model? This could merely be a strange problem on a variant of Android.